# Ganache VM Exception while processing transaction: out of gas

Tags: web3js, javascript, ganache

I am deploying my contract using web3 by taking values (just copy paste) from Etherscan (i.e. abi, contract creation code, etc.) and then deploy my contract on Ganache (gui). When i run the my code through `node deploy.js` following error displayed (However, on Ganache GUI, that command shows that my contract has been deployed and also shows its address).

Here is my code:

```
 async function deployWithCreationCode(){

     var contract = new web3.eth.Contract(abi);
    var dc = await contract.deploy({data: crCode})
          .send({
              from: account1,
              gas: 6721975, // i cannot assign more gas above gas limit of ganache... is it possible to increase this limit.... ?
              gasPrice: '30000000'
          });
return dc._address;
```

}

Here is my error:

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Returned error: VM Exception while processing transaction: out of gas
```

**Note: If size of my contract creation code is less, then  no error at all.**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I cannot assign more gas above gas limit of ganache... is it possible to increase this limit.... ?

Yes, start Ganache with `--gasLimit=someHigherValue`.

That being said, note that 6721975 is already by itself a pretty high value for a single transaction, so your deployment most likely fails for a different reason (`"out of gas"` is unfortunately quite a misleading error-message, but I think that Web3.js dev team are aware of that and are working towards fixing it in a future release).

In order to check whether or not your `gas` value is the problem here, replace this:

```
send({from: account1, gas: 6721975, gasPrice: '30000000');
```

With this:

```
estimateGas({from: account1);
```

And then make sure that it completes successfully.

If it does, then your `gas` value is indeed the problem, and you should replace it with whatever the call to `estimateGas` has returned.

Otherwise, your transaction reverts for a different reason, most likely related to the contract function itself (i.e., your contract's constructor).

---

One more thing to notice (which I recently encountered myself and took a lot of effort in figuring out):

Ethereum has a contract code-size limit of 24KB.

If you contract's code-size exceeds this limit, then no matter what you do - whether it's in your contract code or in your deployment code - the contract deployment will fail.

How to check your contract's code-size:

1. If you're compiling via solc executable, then make sure that the size of the output `bin` file does not exceed 48KB
2. If you're compiling via solc.js (for example, via Truffle), then make sure that the size of the `bytecode` field in the output `json` file does not exceed 48KB

Why 48KB?

> 2 hexdecimal characters = 2 bytes in the text file = 1 byte in the actual bytecode.

Comment: if i replaced as you suggested, then i could not deploy any contract... previously i can deploy my contract ... i think if i make transaction like this .... var dc = await contract.deploy({data: crCode})
          .estimateGas({from: account1});'  it should be wrong... (can you give me complete transaction ... ?

Comment: @AmirAli: Sorry, but I don't understand "then i could not deploy any contract". I explained that you should replace `send` with `estimateGas` in order to investigate whether or not your problem is indeed gas-related. Of course you cannot deploy your contract with `estimateGas`, but this was not the purpose to begin with. Did you read my answer carefully enough?

Comment: sorry i understand now. so, there is now no  error... and it complete all my transaction...

Comment: @AmirAli: Did `estimateGas` complete without reverting? Like I said, if it does, then your problem is indeed gas-limit, and you should simply take whatever `estimateGas` returns and use it instead of your current value. Is this indeed the case?

Comment: yes, without revert it... thanks ... i will try then

Comment: @AmirAli: No problem. Let me know if it's working for you...

Comment: Ok i will let you know...